# Temporary tree fully on stack

Tags: c++, stack, option-type, initializer-list, temporary-objects

I want to create a temporary tree (to be given as argument to a certain expression, for example). To do this I don't want to allocate memory but exploit the C++ capabilities to work with temporary values and constexpr maybe.

The tree will be created inline with a syntax similar to the following:

```
temporary_node<int> t(
    n(111)({
        n(222),
        n(333)
    })
);
```

The root `111` have two children: `222` and `333`.
Now, as I want to have a variable number of children, per node, I used `std::initializer_list` to mimic variable arguments function (In order to not use template vararg or the old `<cstdarg>` library (as suggested http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variadic_arguments).

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <iostream>
#include <optional>
using namespace std;

// my node type
template <typename T>
struct temporary_node {
    T value;
    std::optional<std::initializer_list<temporary_node<T>>> children;
    temporary_node(int value) : value(value), children() {}
    temporary_node operator()(std::initializer_list<temporary_node<T>> children) {
        this->children = children;
        return *this;
    }
    std::string print() const {
        std::string result = std::to_string(value); // the problem is here
        if (children.has_value()) {
            result += "(";
            for (auto& child : children.value()) {
                result += child.print() + ", ";
            }
            result += ")";
        }
        return result;
    }
};

// a simple function that generates a node
template <typename T>
temporary_node<T> n(T value) {
    return {value};
}

// program
int main() {
    temporary_node<int> t(
        n(111)({
            n(222),
            n(333)
        })
    );
    cout << t.print() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Just copy past and build with c++17.
The program will print "111(some_garbage, 333, )". The problem is on the highlighted line. When `temporary_node(111)::printf` is called, a read of `temporary_node::value` somehow corrupts `temporary_node::children`.

With the help of the debugger, I verified that immediately before executing `std::string result = std::to_string(value);`, `children` correctly contains `222` but after that it contains just garbage.

Any idea about what happends under the hood?

Comment: `std::initializer_list` isn't a normal container. Check the warnings about lifetime here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list

Comment: I guess its impl-defined. In wandbox.org compiler (GCC 8.0.1) it works.

Comment: @Mat It says the lifetime (of the underlying array) works the same as other temporaries. So I guess it will last until the semicolon. Is this assumption wrong?

Comment: works with clang++ 5.0 on ubuntu xenial. It must be a bug of g++ 7.2.0

Comment: Even tough I am perfectly aware the temporary are destroyed after instruction, I didn't notice that I call method print after the semicolon. It works perfectly.